# Pagespeed Insight doesnt work when im logged in

Tags: pagespeed, google-search-console, google-pagespeed

I dont't know if somebody else has this problem but I gotta log out or open a incognito tab to analyze my web. Something strange also happens with Google Search console, I have to press ctrl+f5 each time y go different parts of the search console. Is very strange ¿any Idea to solve it?

I tried loggin in and out, erasing cookies and navigator history, but the problem stills here.